# In which scenario we need a ReadOnlyCollection?

Tags: .net-4.5

Dotnet 4.5 has introduce [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). My question is what is the practical useage of it? What scenarios we may need this kind of data structure?

Comment: Introduced in .Net 2.0, only the corresponding interfaces like `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` are 4.5 specific.

Answer (score 1):

You need read-only collections when your API returns collection objects to your callers, copying is too expensive, and you would prefer to stay away from returning `IEnumerable<T>`. This is commonly desirable in situations when random access is required over the returned collection.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to return a collection that the caller should not be able to modify, but you still want to have the guarantees that an `IList` gives over an `IEnumerable`, e.g. a free .Count property, an indexer and the ability to safely iterate over it multiple times, both which aren't guaranteed on an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

This class is useful in a multithreading application. In a multithreading environment can it be a real problem to have a collection of objects, which might be changed by some other thread. This assures threadsafety and lessens the complexity of the code.